# Is there anyway to enter a backend other than by its API endpoints?

Tags: mysql, database, security, sql-injection, backend

Supposing I have a backend exposing only one endpoint in only one API

Is this endpoint the only "door" to my database?

If this unique endpoint only takes one parameter as int, or even better, no parameter at all,  is my database protected against all kind of attack?

If it's still vulnerable, please tell me why/How.

EDIT
I've been pointed out that the question is too large. So to be more precise :
Is it possible to enter my database by any other way then by one of my endpoints.

It's a yes or no question, with maybe some additional info if possible in the case of a yes.

Thanks

Comment: This is an Off-topic question. You might find better answers at https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

this is a quite (too) large question. I would consider:

- securing your endpoint: are you sure that any sort of injection on your endpoint is impossible? what if I send strange things like """; drop table ..."""". Another typical and very common threat is a DoS attack, in which your endpoint is flooded by malicious requests
- securing your machine: large topic, but this include firewall, security updates, security policy to define and manage who can and how to connect to this server. If one get access as root to your machine, he'll get access to your db